# Persistent connections across VPN restarts

Tags: linux, networking

I use vpnc on Linux, and with our corporate VPN setup (it's a Cisco something or other router), it's not exactly rock-solid. I run most things inside screen, so it's not a huge deal, but isn't there some way of maintaining connections across VPN restarts?

It seems like if I had a separate router box running vpnc, I would get it for free just by setting that box as my gateway. How can I emulate the same behavior with a single box?

When the VPN restarts, I get a different IP address and MAC address on the tun0 or tap0 device.

I tried playing games by using tap0 for the tunnel and then bridging it to various things (dummy devices, loopbacks, etc.), but couldn't get anything working.

Answer (score 2):

You could run ppp over your VPNed connection to something on the other side that gives you a static IP.  Run all of your stuff over that connection, and make it auto reconnect.

I wouldn't call it pretty, but it would work! :)

Comment: I feel like I got the idea from somewhere... no idea where.

Answer (score 0):

If your IP address changes when the VPN restarts there's really not much you can do about it - the change of IP address is going to kill any active sessions.